# How to disable password prompts when changing something in OS X?

Tags: macos, passwords, osx-lion

If I start MAMP Pro, I need to type the password. If a Flash update is available, I need to type a password. If I install an application, I need to type a password.

Is there a way to stop this annoying request and don't have to type it any more?

I've searched System preferences with no success.

Comment: Well, that's because it's Unix. The password prompts for *system-wide* changes are there for a reason. MAMP will prompt you to use port 80, it shouldn't do that for other unreserved ones. Flash updates are system-wide updates applied to files your user does not own. Same goes for application installers.

Comment: @slhck: So there's no easy way to stop this, is that it ? Ubuntu is also Unix based, and it doesn't ask so many times for my password :p (as far as I recall);

Comment: Really depends on what exactly you want to do. MAMP for example, see here: [Stop password prompt on MAMP startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207786/stop-password-prompt-on-mamp-startup). Application installers? Unlikely. These installers *need* write permissions to stuff your user can't change, which is why you will sooner or later need the admin password. In that case, the question of course is whether the app is well-designed. But still, it's one of the most important security features of Unix.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend this at all, but if you really want to get around this and don't care about the security implications, then you can use the computer as root. If you do this, you leave your system completely open to accidental installation and deletion of important system files, but you will never be prompted for a password again.

1. Open Terminal. Command: sudo passwd root (Enter your password, then your new root password twice.)
2. Logout
3. Login as root using the new password you just created.
4. (Bonus) Open System Preferences > Users > Login Options to have the computer automatically login as root when the computer starts.

Comment: Extra bonus: Any slip can hose the system for good.